# thrown during paint(): 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 544 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, carousel, flutter-web, flutter-test

I want to build a Carousel Slider that shows Product Images of a List I've made earlier, with an onPressed function that Navigates to another Route that shows the details of the tapped product, My product list is of name List< Productz >.

When I call the Carousel Slider method in my Home_Page Route I need "itemBuilder: (context, index)", so I wrapped it in a ListView.builder and wrapped that into a Container with defined height and width to avoid the error above, but on running the app nothing shows in the place where the Carousel Slider is supposed to be.. Am I doing this right?

My Carousel Slider code:

```
    class CustomCarouselHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> Productzz;
  final Function press;
  final Productz productz;

  CustomCarouselHomePage(
      {required this.Productzz, required this.press, required this.productz});

  @override
  _CustomCarouselHomePageState createState() => _CustomCarouselHomePageState();
}

class _CustomCarouselHomePageState extends State<CustomCarouselHomePage> {
  int activeIndex = 0;
   late final Function press;
   late final Productz productz;

  setActiveDot(index) {
    setState(() {
      activeIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: CarouselSlider(
            options: CarouselOptions(
              autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 4),
              autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
              autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(seconds: 2),
              viewportFraction: 1.0,
              onPageChanged: (index,reason) {
                setActiveDot(index);
              },
            ),
            items: widget.Productzz.map((productzz) {
              return Builder(
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => press (),
                    child: Stack(
                     // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        child: Hero(
                          tag: "${productz.id}",
                          child: Image.asset(productz.item_image),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ), );
                },
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          bottom: 10,
          child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: List.generate(widget.Productzz.length, (idx) {
                return activeIndex == idx ? ActiveDot() : InactiveDot();
              })),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ActiveDot extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
      child: Container(
        width: 25,
        height: 8,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InactiveDot extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
      child: Container(
        width: 8,
        height: 8,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: grey,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My code for when I call the Carousel Slider method in Home_Page Route:

```
Container(
  height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
  child: ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => CustomCarouselHomePage(
    Productzz: [],
    productz: productz[index],
    press: () => Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => DetailsScreen(
            productz: productz[index],
          ),
        )),
  ),
),),
```